# UPDATE AND INSERT multiple rows into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote this code to insert multiple rows into database, and I need to update duplicates .

```
    INSERT INTO `me_cities`( `from`, `destination`, `price`, `updated`)
 VALUES 
('ERR','MRHD','91,000',now()),
('ERR','KIH','106,800',now()),
('ERR','SYZ','86,000',now()),
('ERR','AWZ','121,000',now()),
('ERR','IFN','116,741',now()),
('ERR','GSM','111,000',now()),
('ERR','NJF','141,000',now()),
('ERR','IST','351,000',now()),
('ERR','BND','116,000',now()),
('ERR','DEF','120,200',now()),
('ERR','','151,000',now()),
('ERR','BUZ','161,000',now()) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=VALUES(price),`updated`=VALUES(now());
```

But I have error on this query.
I need to update the row if only *from* and *destination* field are as same as next row.

Comment: Try `updated=now()` instead of `updated=VALUES(now())`

Comment: I am looking for a where condition in that query so I can update price and time for those which have same from and destination value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your topic , I think you should do something like this :

```
 INSERT INTO `me_cities`( `from`, `destination`, `price`, `updated`)
 VALUES 
('ERR','MRHD','91,000',now()),
('ERR','KIH','106,800',now()),
('ERR','SYZ','86,000',now()),
('ERR','AWZ','121,000',now()),
('ERR','IFN','116,741',now()),
('ERR','GSM','111,000',now()),
('ERR','NJF','141,000',now()),
('ERR','IST','351,000',now()),
('ERR','BND','116,000',now()),
('ERR','DEF','120,200',now()),
('ERR','','151,000',now()),
('ERR','BUZ','161,000',now())
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=VALUES(`price`),`updated`=VALUES(`updated`);
```

UPDATE , if you want to update every each of them, first make the from and destination columns unique and relevant unique keys , something like this query

```
  INSERT INTO `me_cities`( `from`, `destination`, `price`, `updated`)
     VALUES 
    ('ERR','MRHD','91,000',now()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=''  ,`updated`=now() ;
INSERT INTO `me_cities`( `from`, `destination`, `price`, `updated`)
     VALUES 
    ('ERR','MRHD','91,000',now())ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price`=''  ,`updated`=now() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate and execute this commands

```
UPDATE `me_cities` SET `price`='91,000', `updated`=now() WHERE EXIST (SELECT WHERE `from`='ERR'  AND `destination`='MRHD` AND `price`='91,000' AND `updated`=now())
```

Comment: I want to have insert and update command on one query , So if there is no row with same from and destination value , then Insert otherwise update the price of that row

Comment: generate two command. First for update - above coomand, second for insert: INSERT INTO `me_cities`( `from`, `destination`, `price`, `updated`) VALUES WHERE NOT EXIST SELECT WHERE `from`='ERR'  AND `destination`='MRHD` AND price`='91,000' AND `updated`=now()